# WPF Slider Control Mouse Wheel

Tags: wpf

I've got a WPF Slider,  the Mousewheel Eventhandler is all wired up and its working fine, However, the area of the slider where the mouse wheel takes effect is very very narrow and I need to have my mouse right over the slider rail - which is about 5 pixels.

How can I increase the area of influence for mousewheel activation?

UPDATE:

Btw I need to do it in code, I don't have access to Xaml as I am adding something to a third party application.

UPDATE 2:

Here's my code for creating the slider:

```
        var riskRewardSlider = new Slider()
        {
            Minimum = 1,
            Maximum = 5,
            SmallChange = 0.5,
            TickFrequency = 0.5,
            DataContext = scopeContext,
            IsSnapToTickEnabled = true, 
            Value = 2,
            Background = Brushes.DodgerBlue,
            Height = 30,
            IsSelectionRangeEnabled = true
        };
```

Comment: Use another control template for the slider.

Comment: I'm new to WPF - I'm a web developer.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://wpftutorial.net/Templates.html) is a good tutorial.

Comment: How do you create the Slider? It seems that the Background of your control is set to be null. Set the Background to Transparent.

Comment: Nope setting it to transparent made the track disappear.  It seems the background property only affects the track..... I really just need to make the track thicker

Comment: I updated my answer with the code for creating the slider

Answer (score 1):

Slider value is changes with doubles. It count 0.1 or less sensitive about that.If i understand correctly,you don't want to increase like 0,1. So;

```
mySlider.IsSnapToTickEnabled = true;
mySlider.TickFrequency = 1;
```

You can add that on your starting method. (or you can add this on your xaml as attributes, but you want as code). This makes your slider increase by **1**, instead of 0,1.

Note: That 0,1 is just an double example, Slider's less sensitive than 0,1 by default.

Note2: Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  And welcome to StackOverflow.  My question was actually about the hover-area - the mouse needs to be in a very exact place over the track or the mouse wheel doesn't work.

Comment: Can't you just add this mousewheel event on entire window? So you no longer need that area.

If you don't wanna entire window, you can create a (stackpanel etc.) with your height, and add that event on your stackpanel?

Comment: That could work, but there are two sliders right next to each other, both on the same panel, I need to split them somehow.  Is they anything simple I can put them in - just a box

Comment: If you can add a box, (Have enough space for it) you can inscrease size of sliders, or add a margin for it.

But, if you wanna add them in a box, add Borderthickness and Borderbrush. Wheel is trigger its event, even mouse cursor is on the border.